# How to define the prototyp for a method which expect istream

Tags: c++, methods

I have the following code:

```
int readInt(istream &stream)
{
    int i;
    stream >> i;
    return i;
}
```

Could anyone tell me how I have to declrate the prototyp of this method, that im able to copy the code after my main(). I have tried `int readInt(istream)`, but that seems not to work.

Comment: what is the error message? (note that your code lacks header includes and std namespace)

Comment: Namespace is included. One Second i have to translate the error message.

Comment: Just copy from the definition: `int readInt(istream &stream);` (or `int readInt(istream &);`). The parameter type is `istream &` - reference to `istream` - not `istream`.

Comment: Intellisense: several instance of overloaded function matches the argument list: 
Function "readInt(std::istream);
Function "readInt(std::istream &stream);

Comment: @molbdnilo solved the problem, but I really cant understand why.. :D

Comment: @Matej You declared a function with the prototype `int readInt(istream)` and defined one with the prototype `int readInt(istream &)`. Both prototypes match an `istream` variable and do it "equally well". If you move the definition after `main` you will get a link error about "undefined symbols".

Answer (score 0):

You forgot reference in arguments list in prototype. Should be: `int readInt(istream &);`